# Javascript/Canvas - Why is my variable being incremented and why is the if statement executing?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a tile based map that a player can press a key button to move a 32x32 sized image across a canvas. Each time the right arrow is released, the small image should move to the right by 32 'units' (I am assuming its pixels).

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',domloaded,false);

var CANVAS_WIDTH = 768;
var CANVAS_HEIGHT = 512;
var World_Width = 3;
var World_Height = 7;

let pX = 0; //players current X position
let pY = 0; //players current Y position
let currentWorld;
let WorldX = 0; //players current X position in area map array (LEFT and RIGHT)
let WorldY = 0; //players current Y position in area map array (UP and DOWN)

//Reset X and Y
WorldX = 0;
WorldY = 0;
```

The above is all the variables. The next code is used for loading a few images. I don't think the issue is here.

```
//Wait for loading - all good here
function domloaded(){
    var c = document.getElementById("gameBoard");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    console.log ("Drawing Map....");
    window.onload = function(){         
        ctx.drawImage(WorldImgArray[0],0,0);
        console.log('Set pX to 0 from NOWHERE!!!!!!');
        ctx.drawImage(player, 0, 0, 32, 32);
    }
```

This next bit is catching keypress/releases.

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', pControls, false);

    function pControls(e){

        switch (e.keyCode){
            case 39:
                rightArrow();
                break;
            case 37:
                leftArrow();
                break;
            case 38:
                upArrow();
                break;
            case 40:
                downArrow();
                break;
        }
    }
```

While I don't think leftArrow() function is messing me up, I still list it here just in case I am missing something. But I do have all other functions declared, none of which modifies pX so I am only posting rightArrow and leftArrow below.

```
function leftArrow() {
    // Set up map transitions if needed
        if (pX > 0 && WorldX >= 0) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
            pX -= 32;
            drawMap();
            //ctx.drawImage(player, pX, pY, 32, 32);
            console.log(WorldX);
        } else console.log("Y !> 0");
    }

    function rightArrow() {
        if (pX < CANVAS_WIDTH - 32){
            //ctx.clearRect(0,0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
            pX += 32;
            console.log('Drew from NORMAL rightArrow!');
            console.log('pX = ' + pX);
            drawMap();
            console.log(WorldX);
            //ctx.drawImage(player, pX, pY, 32, 32);
        } else if (pX == CANVAS_WIDTH - 32 && WorldX < World_Width){
            console.log ("Screen Transition!!");
            WorldX+=1;
            currentArea+=1;
            pX = 0;
            drawMap();

            //ctx.drawImage(player, pX, pY, 32, 32);
        } else if (pX = CANVAS_WIDTH - 32 && WorldX == World_Width){
            return;
        }

    }
```

And finally, my draw function.

```
function drawMap(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        ctx.drawImage(WorldImgArray[currentArea],0,0);
        ctx.drawImage(player, pX, pY, 32, 32);
        console.log("X: " + pX + " Y: " + pY);
     }
```

Now, each time I press the right arrow on my keyboard...the player image moves 32 to the right. Once it reaches the end of the canvas, it move player back to the beginning of the canvas and displays a new image that covers the entire canvas. This should happen 4 times before the player runs out of "room". The best way to explain is that WorldX = 0 is the starting line and WorldX = 3 is the finish line, I need to "disable" movement to the right when player is at the edge of the canvas and WorldX = 3. And that is where my problem lies.

When the player is at the edge of the canvas and worldX = 3, I can press the right arrow key once, nothing happens...but when I press it a second time, the player is moved to the left side of the canvas + 1 'unit' more than it should. Movement is supposed to happen in 32 units, but when the above bug occurs it starts moving by 33. The increment by 1 only happens once, but player moves from the far right edge of canvas to the far left of canvas each time I double press right arrow while at the edge of the canvas.

TLDR; why does pX get incremented by 1 and the player get moved back to the left edge when the else if in rightArrow is true? With console.log I was able to discern that the if statement in rightArrow is actually drawing when the conditions are false?!?! What is going on?

Comment: something I noticed: `} else if (pX = CANVAS_WIDTH - 32...` should be `} else if (pX == CANVAS_WIDTH - 32...`